# How to allow insert data even if there's a null in the request?

Tags: laravel

I have code like this:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{

        $siswa_id = $request->siswa_id;
        $mapel_id = $request->mapel_id;
        $uh1 = $request->uh1;
        $uh2 = $request->uh2;
        $pts_ganjil = $request->pts_ganjil;
        $uh3 = $request->uh3;

foreach($mapel_id as $key => $mapel)
        {
            $input['siswa_id'] = $siswa_id;
            $input['mapel_id'] = $mapel;
            $input['uh1'] = $uh1[$key];
            $input['uh2'] = $uh2[$key];
            $input['pts_ganjil'] = $pts_ganjil[$key];
            $input['uh3'] = $uh3[$key];

            Nilai::create($input);

       }
}
```

It give error `Trying to access array offset on value of type null` if there's a null value from request.
How to keep insert to database even if there's a null value from request? I have set it to nullable but still didn't work.

The error is inside looping foreach because the variable to store request is null.
But i don't have any idea how to do that, I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass like this it checks there if a key exists in array then get value from it otherwise value will be `null`

```
foreach($mapel_id as $key => $mapel)
        {
            $input['siswa_id'] = $siswa_id;
            $input['mapel_id'] = $mapel;
            $input['uh1'] = ($uh1 !== null) ? (array_key_exists($key,$uh1)) ? $uh1[$key] : null : null;
            $input['uh2'] = ($uh2 !== null) ? (array_key_exists($key,$uh2)) ? $uh2[$key] : null : null;
            $input['pts_ganjil'] = ($pts_ganjil !== null) ?  (array_key_exists($key,$pts_ganjil)) ? $pts_ganjil[$key] : null : null;
            $input['uh3'] = ($uh3 !== null) ? (array_key_exists($key,$uh3)) ? $uh3[$key] : null : null;

            Nilai::create($input);

       }
```

Comment: I get another error, array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: So it means in request you got the `null` value.

Comment: Yes sir, that is my question. It is posible to insert a null value if my request is null?